# Autofill excel formula from left to right using python

Tags: python, autofill, xlwings

I've a input excel with 4 columns.
Step1: To add a new column (col 5)
Step2 : Drag the formula from col 4 to col 5.

[If you see here I got col 'D' from col 'C'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zMBi.png)

[Similarly col 'C' using col 'B'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuHkw.png)

Now I just want to create a new col using col 'D'. Output should look like below.

[Result should be as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikK0E.png)

I want to automate this using python.

Things I tried.
I tried the autofill method in xlwings, but it only works from top to bottom cells. Like E2:E7.
I want to fill D2:E2 first and then E2:E7 is easy using the below code.

```
import xlwings as xw
from xlwings.constants import AutoFillType
wb = xw.Book(r'C:\Users\Sandeep\Downloads/FormulaDragTest.xlsx')
sheet = wb.sheets(1)
sheet.range('E2').api.AutoFill(sheet.range("E2:E7")).api,
                           AutoFillType.xlFillDefault)
```